# Correct Way to determine if function is set

Tags: php, function, post, isset

i cant seem to find a solution to my issue. im trying to check if the value of a function has been set and if it has do some stuff however when i run the below codes the bottom one throws a error the code at the bottom is the code i wish to use

seems pointless calling the function into a variable just to see if its set

```
//working check if set
$wa_passwordreset = WA_FN_Validate_Post($_POST['wa_passwordreset']);
if(isset($wa_passwordreset))
{
echo"do some stuff";
}

//NOT working check if set
if(isset( WA_FN_Validate_Post($_POST['wa_passwordreset']) ))
{
echo"do some other stuff";
}
```

Comment: no need to `isset` then. a simple `if( WA_FN_Validate_Post($_POST['wa_passwordreset']))` can do it

Comment: @roullie, if `WA_FN_Validate_Post` returns a number of faulty characters in a string (or anything relevant to that, a number of errors or whatever), your suggestion may then evaluate to `false` even if it should be evaluated to `true`, which is essentially wrong.

Comment: the function sanitizes post data and i will need to check after its sanitized if its set

Comment: @Nordenheim your insights might be true.  since you added an `if` the `function`.

Comment: @Nathan please read my answer. The variable will always be set even if the function returns an empty string or a zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> isset — Determine if a **variable** is set and is not NULL

`isset` actually test if a *variable* is set, not if a function returns any value. That is why your code doesn't work.

> im trying to check if the value of a function has been set

Functions do *not* have values. Functions may return values. You can't check if a function has a value and if it's set.

Moreover,

```
$wa_passwordreset = WA_FN_Validate_Post($_POST['wa_passwordreset']);
if(isset($wa_passwordreset))
{
    echo "do some stuff";
}
```

this portion of code will **always** return true. The reason for that is that even if `WA_FN_Validate_Post` would return an empty string, the variable `$wa_passwordreset` will be considered set and `isset` check will always return `true`. To avoid this, you should either check your `$_POST` like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['wa_passwordreset']))
{
    $wa_passwordreset = WA_FN_Validate_Post($_POST['wa_passwordreset']);
    echo "do some stuff";
}
```

Or if it's vital for you to maintain the order and check after `WA_FN_Validate_Post`, use `empty`:

```
$wa_passwordreset = WA_FN_Validate_Post($_POST['wa_passwordreset']);
if(isset($wa_passwordreset) && !empty($wa_passwordreset)) // be extra paranoid!
{
    echo "do some stuff";
}
```

Comment: thank you this was what i was looking for. thank you for taking the time to help me